# How to skip space in a SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to alter credentials using this SQL query:

```
ALTER CREDENTIAL credential_name WITH IDENTITY = 'identity_name'
  [ , SECRET = 'secret' ]
```

And the issue is that my `credential_name` has a space in it. So that would make my query look something like:

```
ALTER CREDENTIAL HCC SQL WITH IDENTITY = 'username', SECRET = 'password';
```

Running this, I get these errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
> Incorrect syntax near 'SQL'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

So I was wondering if there is a way to skip the space in this query?

Or would I have to change my credential_name to something with no spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most entity names in SQL Server, you can use square brackets around your credential's name:

```
ALTER CREDENTIAL [HCC SQL] WITH IDENTITY = 'username', SECRET = 'password';
```

This works in my local instance of SQL Server 15.